# past which... -- not sure how to understand that

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Networking—A Beginner's Guide, 5th Edition by Bruce Hallberg (2010)](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Networking_A_Beginner_s_Guide_Fifth_Edit.html?id=bYOiQWBTSS0C&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> Managing multiple processors requires a lot of overhead work on the part of the operating system. Because of this, having twice as many processors in a computer doesn't double its processing capability; instead, doubling the processors might improve the computer's speed by only about 50 percent. Depending on your operating system, there is also a point of diminishing returns, **past** which additional processors won’t give you much additional performance.

How exactly do you understand that **past** here? Is it functioning as a preposition or an adverb?

Comment: Replacing "past which" with "beyond that" (and a bit of rephrasing) might help: "Depending on your operating system, there is also a point of diminishing returns. *Beyond that,* additional processors won’t give you much additional performance."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case "past" functions in the same way as "to go *past* something".  The idiom "past which" is shorthand for "if you go *past* this point, then ..."

Other examples:

> The paved road goes only to the next town, **past which** you'll be riding on dirt.
>
> I can only give you enough money for expenses to the end of the month, **past which** you are on your own.
>
> The body can only absorb a certain dosage of many vitamins each day, **past which** you're just wasting money.